# How to use Lombok @SuperBuilder with customized builder and several classes in hierarchy of heritance?

Tags: java, lombok

I have such classes hierarchy:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent1 {
    Long id;
}
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent2 extends Parent1 {
    String name;

    // Customized Lombok's builder
    public abstract static class Parent2Builder<C extends Parent2, B extends Parent2Builder<C, B>> {...}
}
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent2 {
    //some fields and methods
}
```

All worked fine when Parent1 and Parent2 were as one class (Parent with 2 fields) with Lombok's customized builder. But I had to separate one class in two different and got the next error while compiling:
Parent2.java: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype @SuperBuilder

I have no idea which method I didn't implement.

P.S. I also have the same classes hierarchy (but without customized builder) in another package and there were no errors at all.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the fix you are looking for, but it works for me if I define `public abstract static class Parent2Builder<C extends Parent2, B extends Parent2Builder<C, B>> extends Parent1.Parent1Builder<C, B> {...}`. --- A remark: You may want to add `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)` tot `Parent2` and `Child`.

Comment: Seems this is exactly the fix that I'm looking for :)
I've added extends Parent1.Parent1Builder<C, B> {...} to my customized builder and this solution works. Many thanks

Comment: You should really use delombok when customizing your `@SuperBuilder`. C&P from the Eclipse outline does not work. The class definitions are very complex due to the heavy generics usage, it's almost impossible to get them right manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `Parent2.Parent2Builder` does no longer `extends Parent1.Parent1Builder`. If we change

```
public abstract static class Parent2Builder
        <C extends Parent2, B extends Parent2Builder<C, B>> {
    ...
}
```

to

```
public abstract static class Parent2Builder
        <C extends Parent2, B extends Parent2Builder<C, B>> 
        extends Parent1.Parent1Builder<C, B> {
    ...
}
```

It works as expected.